# Hide other shipping options when Free shipping is available for one zone only in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I need a way to achieve the following: If Free Shipping is available, AND the order is being shipped to a specific zone, hide all other shipping methods.

I found this snippet:

```
function hide_shipping_when_free_is_available( $rates ) {
    $free = array();
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_when_free_is_available', 100 );
```

How would I add a conditional into it to only apply it to orders going to one zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will hide all other shipping methods when free shipping is available for a specific Zone (you will define in the function the targeted zone ID or Zone name):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'free_shipping_hide_others_by_zone', 100, 2 );
function free_shipping_hide_others_by_zone( $rates, $package ) {

    // HERE define your shipping zone ID OR the shipping zone name
    $defined_zone_id   = '';
    $defined_zone_name = 'Europe';

    // Get The current WC_Shipping_Zone Object
    $zone      = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_matching_package( $package );
    $zone_id   = $zone->get_id(); // The zone ID
    $zone_name = $zone->get_zone_name(); // The zone name

    $free      = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop through shipping rates
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id && ( $zone_id == $defined_zone_id || $zone_name == $defined_zone_name ) ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Hide shipping rates when free shipping is available.
 * Updated to support WooCommerce 2.6 Shipping Zones.
 *
 * @param array $rates Array of rates found for the package.
 * @return array
 */
function my_hide_shipping_when_free_is_available( $rates ) {
    $free = array();
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'my_hide_shipping_when_free_is_available', 100 );
```